# EditText focus issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I've got an issue with several EditText components which reside side-by-side (They are children of RelativeLayout).

```
                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/num1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:maxLength="1"                    
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/num2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/num1"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"                    
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/num3"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/num2"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"                    
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                />
```

Also, following is the relevant code that tries to change focus from num1 component to num2 component, but actually what happens is that the focus goes from num1 to num3:

```
        final EditText etLastNumber1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
    final EditText etLastNumber2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2);
        etLastNumber1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (Misc.IsKeyCodeNumber(keyCode)) {
                etLastNumber1.clearFocus();
                etLastNumber2.requestFocus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I've tried different variations of the same code, including not to use clearFocus and/or always return true. Also, the parent layout uses descendantFocusability=beforeDescendants and focusableInTouchMode=true.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: try android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on your relative layout

Comment: @SathishKumarJ I've tried your suggestion... what happens is that neither of the components gets focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after few weeks of developing other aspects in the android app, I've returned to this issue and I've found the way to fix this issue.

The issue is primarily with context to the Key Events that might happen during the input and focused components.

That said, I've added to the OnKeyListener method the highlighted conditions:

```
                if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SOFT_LEFT && event.getAction() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SOFT_RIGHT && Misc.IsKeyCodeNumber(keyCode)) {

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try one of them:

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/.."  
android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/.."    
android:nextFocusRight="@+id/.."    
android:nextFocusUp="@+id/.."
```

Example:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/num1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:maxLength="1"                    
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/num2"
                />
```

Comment: the implementation of setOnKeyListener states that I want to set focus to another component when the user inputs a number character